# Unwanted sites pop up frequently in Mozila Firefox

Tags: firefox, popups

Whenever I open up any site, some unwanted sites are opening other sites. How can I prevent my computer from opening the unwanted sites? I am using  Mozilla Firefox.

Most of the sites are adult sites.

Comment: Sounds like a virus to me. Boot into safemode if possible and run a scan

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the right forum for this type of question, but you probably have adware/malware.

Download [MalwareBytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/mbam.php) and run a scan.

Answer (score 1):

It's clear that you have malware.  In addition to taking the appropriate steps to remove the infection, you should take the proper steps to prevent this from happening again.  Firefox has many nice extensions that can protect your browser from such things such as [NoScript](http://noscript.net/), which can be downloaded through the add-ons section of your browser.  I would also of course suggest Adblock Plus, which I think any Firefox install is naked without.

Answer (score 0):

Check for any suspect add-ons (possibly with not so suspect names).

**Besides** installing their malware as a startup application in Windows, some malware programmers are gone one step beyond, and has written add-ons for Firefox. Definitely worth checking...